# Wait for all content in AJAX response to be loaded before displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a search function where on every character it pings the server with a json request to return the results. That part of it all works, but what I'd love to have happen (which I can't figure out) is to also put a loading class on .search-load>.container and then wait for all the images and content that have been requested to load completely before removing the loading class.

Everytime i try and tie a .load function onto the removeClass function it ends up just leaving the loading class on there. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
$(document).on('keyup','#section-dropdown.search input',function(event){
            if(searchTimer !== null){
                clearTimeout(searchTimer);
            }
            var query = this.value;
            searchTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.search-load > .container').addClass('loading');
                    $.getJSON('json/search.json?query='+query,function(data){
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            var html = ''; 
                            for(var i=0,item=data[i];i<data.length;i++){
                                html +='<a class="entry small search" href="'+item.link+'"><article>';
                                html +='<div class="image"><img src="'+item.picture+'" alt="'+item.alt+'"></div>';
                                html +='<div class="content"><h1>'+item.title+'</h1></div></article></a>';
                                if(i==data.length-1){
                                    $('.search-load > .container').html(html);
                                    $('.search-load > .container').removeClass('loading');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

            },200);

});
```

Comment: why dont you call $('.search-load > .container').removeClass('loading'); after the if block.

Comment: @cyril thanks, that does remove it but i'd also like to have it wait until the content that is being added is completely loaded (namely the images). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would delegate onload event but as it doesn't bubble, you cannot. So you could still capture it if IE8< support isn't an issue.

```
document.addEventListener(
  'load',
  function (event) {
    var elm = event.target;
    if (elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img' && $(elm).closest('.search-load > .container').length && !$(elm).hasClass('loaded')) { // or any other filtering condition
      console.log('image loaded');
      $(elm).addClass('loaded');
      if ($('.search-load > .container img.loaded').length === $('.search-load > .container img').length) {
        // do some stuff
        console.log("All images loaded!");
        $('.search-load > .container').removeClass('loading');
      }
    }
  },
  true // Capture event
);
```

You can set this snippet in `head` section of site without any wrapper.

***As a side note:*** jQuery doesn't support capturing phase, that's why you need to use relevant javascript method instead.